# Is this a good method to make money in stock trading?

Tags: stocks, starting-out-investing

I've decided to start a career in stocks and since I initially decided that option, I've taken at least 10 hours a day to look up stock prices and think about methods to use. But I'm still stuck on a few things, mostly the best method to take for day trading to make at least a few hundred a day. So would this method be at least a correct way?

Suppose you have $150 and you see a stock for $3 a share. If you put the $150 into it for 50 shares, could it increase up to at least $7 per share, allowing you to sell your 50 shares for $350? I would hope it was more than that but looking at how some stocks increase it seems like that's maybe too good to be true. If this is not the case, what are some methods I can use to make at least a few hundred a day?

Comment: How large is your initial capital? $150?

Comment: like the initial amount i have to spend? yeah, like i said, say you start with 150

Comment: You want to make hundreds of dollars per day in the stock market by investing only $150?!

Comment: i want to start from there, im new to all of this, and want to start with 150 and make a good amount and be able to make as much money a day as possible and have the amount of daily gains grow, so how do i start from there? i want a fast start

Comment: Anecdotally, it's reported that 90% of wanna be get rich quick day traders lose money. What makes you think that you’re going to be in that top 10%?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a clearly fake.

Comment: Average stock increases are commonly assumed as 7-10% **ANNUALLY**. At 7% after inflation, you double your money every 10 years. To make $100 / day with 7% annual growth, you can withdraw 4% annually, so that would be $36k / year, which would need a balance of about $1M. To turn $150 initial capital into $1M, you would need about 130 years of growth at 10% / year.

Comment: no, this is not fake, i literally starting out and want to know how to get a good start, i've always wanted to get rich and was always told that this was the way to go, but over the last few years ive had many life issues come into play and have had to recently rethink my life, i want to take this route cause i've been told if i learned enough about it i could make something big of myself, im really good with numbers, i understand them better than i understand words at times, i do computer programming as a hobby but want to try this, i just need somebody to help me make my first moves

Comment: okay so where do i start then to make at least a daily income, everybody is giving me the formula for calculating the outcome but nobody is telling me how to make the first move! i can go from the first move, i can be a quick learner and just need to know where to start from

Comment: @PokemonFanboy666 You are talking about gambling, not investing. If you are being serious and this isn't a troll, I strongly encourage you to reach out for help from those around you in your personal life, because this type of aggressive risk taking is worrying.

Comment: @PokemonFanboy666 No. There is no 'first move' here. Look at my rough calculation above - you would need **130 years** to be able to reasonably make $100 / day, off of an initial $150 investment. It just isn't possible. And most importantly: **anyone who tells you it is possible, is going to try and scam you.** There is nothing that truly successful you can rely on. Not even close.

Comment: i literally have nobody around me in real life who knows about this, i live in the west side of canada and my friend who ive known for 5 years and lives on the east side of canada is slowly getting me into this, he's learning from people around him but i also want to take the initiative to learn some things, we are helping each other out so we can become big together

Comment: @PokemonFanboy666 The people encouraging your friend like this are scammers. As are all the people trying to get you into crypto. It is vaporware, there is no value. Anyone who says you can do this with stocks is also scamming you. You are asking to get something like 100,000% return, when 10% annual return is the average.

Comment: i dont have to make that much a day, i just want to, but i at least need a daily income, as long as i can get a daily(or i guess even weekly) income from this, id be happy

Comment: @PokemonFanboy666 Invest in yourself, get an education, get a job, get a hobby, volunteer - all of these things will enrich your life more than gambling with scams.

Comment: nobody was telling me i could make $100 a day, that was just my thinking from using some basic math with the increase rate i had supposed was the real deal, its still a slow process with knowing where to start and how much i can safely make, all i want is a source i can site where i can better understand how to make a career out of this

Comment: @PokemonFanboy666 You can't. Not with $150, and not with your current level of knowledge. This is like driving up to Alaska in February in shorts and a t-shirt, asking how to get a quick start on a gold mine. You are at risk of being taken advantage of.

Comment: thats what im asking for, education on this, i got myself into some legal issues and cant really get a job where i am(plus i would like to move out of my city, its not safe here), even if i could, a 'real' job doesnt pay enough for me, and i did make more than i ever had with crypto(though still not much), i want to do something like this, all im asking for is possible links to sources to learn from

Comment: https://www.sauder.ubc.ca/

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon the account seems valid.

Comment: Please take a look at these relevant questions: [How can I invest my $100?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/14024/how-can-i-invest-my-100), [Micro-investing: How to effectively invest frequent small amounts of money in equities?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/9948/micro-investing-how-to-effectively-invest-frequent-small-amounts-of-money-in-eq), [How to start buying shares with small amount of money?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/74281/how-to-start-buying-shares-with-small-amount-of-money)

Comment: If you can find out all you need to know to get rich by asking on a web site, why isn't everyone rich?

Answer (score 5):

To make a few hundred dollars a day, you should start with about $500,000, not $150. In other words, your expectations are totally unrealistic.

You cannot reliably make a >100% return in one day, or even one year. After the fact, yes, you can identify stocks that went from $3 to $7, but it cannot be predicted beforehand.

A high-leverage options strategy might provide a significant chance of a >100% return, but it would also carry a large risk of a 100% loss. About the same as playing roulette. Sooner or later, you would go bankrupt.

Comment: okay, but how can i get a quick start, im on a disability check monthly but want something better than that, i started getting into cryptocurrency, but thats not fast enough, and if i were to start with half a million to make a few hundred a day wouldnt that be a loss, cause if im correct, if you put 100,000 in a stock and took it out later that day when it went up, wouldnt you come out with a couple hundred thousands? it seems logical to me and thats what i understand, my schooling only made me do math my entire high school life so i thought this would be easy to grasp

Comment: what i want to know, is how much can a beginner make daily with a good starting method?

Comment: @PokemonFanboy666 You are looking for a shortcut that doesn't exist. For a stock to double in a day is very unusual, not routine; and for it to be *the one you bought* is incredible luck. Typically, a stock moves up *or* down (like a coin flip) by a *couple percent* each day. So even if you guess right, you don't make anything like 100%. Even the best-equipped professional investors struggle to beat the S&P 500 index, which returns about 10% *per year*. You need to recalibrate. For now, *your* key variables to build wealth are income, expenses, and savings, not investment returns.

Comment: okay, so how exactly do i start? cause in reality, i dont need $100 a day just yet, i do want to grow to that however, what i need, is to be able to make daily income of any sort, then with that income i can grow my portfolio, and with my daily income, i can put more into stocks as time goes by and have that increase, right? so if possible can you also link some sources i can site for better understanding of how to get a good start

Comment: @PokemonFanboy666 - I know the answer, but I'm not telling you, because that would dilute my getting rich profits. Why would I share such knowledge with anyone?

Comment: PokemonFanboy666 - It's not rare for low priced stocks or leveraged options to double in a short period of time.  With extreme luck you could double or triple your money in no time if your first few positions are winners.  But it's also possible that your first few positions will be losers and with such a small amount of capital ($150), you'll be wiped out easily.  As one of the few traders here, I can tell you that it takes years of effort to be able to become consistent positive and your entire premise of a quick start and getting rich is a fantasy.

Comment: @PokemonFanboy666 You are gambling your disability check on Crypto? That is an exceedingly bad idea. If I were asked to write a story about the most foolish concept imaginable, this would be my thesis.

Answer (score 1):

> Suppose you have $150 and you see a stock for $3 a share. If you put the $150 into it for 50 shares, could it increase up to at least $7 per share, allowing you to sell your 50 shares for $350?

It *could*.  Or it could decrease and you would lose money.  You can't know ahead of time which will happen.  So putting your whole $150 into one stock and hoping it will go up is not much better than just gambling it on a turn of a roulette wheel.

> If this is not the case, what are some methods I can use to make at least a few hundred a day?

There is no way to reliably make a few hundred dollars a day by trading with only $150.  It is like asking "what are some methods I can use to build a nice house in two weeks with just a box of toothpicks".  It isn't going to work.

As people explained in the comments, one obvious reason is that, if there were such a way, everyone would do it.  There's not some magic secret that lets you make hundreds of dollars a day for free.

The most straightforward way to earn hundreds of dollars a day is to get a decent paying job.